# Excel VBA - Replacing Value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace the numbers 91, 92, 93, 94, 99 with 91H, 92H, 93H, 94H, 99H.
But every time I run the macro a second time, the macro adds another H to the number and it looks like 91H**H** for example. I can't find a solution for this. I don't want that the macro adds another H to the number. I want that the macro only adds a H to the new values, not to the ones that have already been changed.

```
Columns("D").Replace What:="92", _
                        Replacement:="92H", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("D").Replace What:="93", _
                        Replacement:="93H", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("D").Replace What:="91", _
                        Replacement:="91H", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("D").Replace What:="94", _
                        Replacement:="94H", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("D").Replace What:="99", _
                        Replacement:="99H", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I didn't post the whole VBA code because it's a little bit long.

Comment: How are these numbers, in a cell 92,93,94 or single cells with 92 and another cell 93.

Comment: Perhaps change `xlPart` to `xlWhole`?  Or, if it is part of text, maybe change `" 92 "` to `" 92H "`?

Comment: One number per cell, xlWhole did the job! Please make a Answer and I will accept it :-), thanks! Sometimes it can be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you are repeating lots of code. This should be avoided. A way to do it is like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceSomething(columnName As String, lookFor As String, replaceWith As String)

    Dim rngCol      As Range
    Dim rngCells    As Range

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(columnName)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set rngCol = Columns(columnName).SpecialCells(2)
    If rngCol Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each rngCells In rngCol
        If rngCells = lookFor Then
            rngCells = replaceWith
        End If
    Next rngCells

End Sub

Sub TestMe()

    ReplaceSomething "A", "H", "H1"
    ReplaceSomething "B", "H", "H1"
    ReplaceSomething "D", "H", "H1"

End Sub
```

Thus you would be giving the Column Name as an argument of the function ReplaceSomething and it will run for columns A, B and C.

Answer (score 0):

I think of a workaround. Add codes before the macro to replace 91H, 92H, 93H, 94H, 99H with 91, 92, 93, 94, 99. What the new macro would do is:
A. "91H": remove "H" and add "H", ie do nothing
B. "91": dont fit into first part, "H" will be added in 2nd part

This should work for any text seen.